# How to concatenate two string environment /w env stanza in Upstart?

Tags: upstart

Here is a part of my .conf file.

```
env SERVICE_ROOT="/data/service_root"
env LOG_DIR="$SERVICE_ROOT/logs"
```

and I checked all variables with following..

```
echo "\n`env`" >> /tmp/listener.log 2>&1
```

I expect that $LOG_DIR is "/data/service_root/logs" but what I got is..

```
SERVICE_ROOT=/data/service_root
LOG_DIR=$SERVICE_ROOT/logs
```

Did I miss something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Defined environment variable is not accessible to the Job Configuration File itself.

> Upstart allows you to set environment variables which **will be accessible to the jobs** whose job configuration files they are defined in.

As explained in [8.2 Environment Variables](http://upstart.ubuntu.com/cookbook/#environment-variables):

> Note that a Job Configuration File does not have access to a user's environment variables, not even the superuser. This is not possible since all job processes created are children of init which does not have a user's environment.

Defined variable $SERVICE_ROOT is accessible to defined job.

```
# /etc/init/test.conf
env SERVICE_ROOT="/data/service_root"

script
  export LOG_DIR="$SERVICE_ROOT/logs"
  # prints "LOG_DIR='/data/service_root/logs'" to system log
  logger -t $0 "LOG_DIR='$LOG_DIR'"
  exec /home/vagrant/test.sh >> /tmp/test.log
end script
```

Variable $LOG_DIR exported in *script* block is available for processes called within the same block.

```
#!/bin/bash -e
# /home/vagrant/test.sh
echo "running test.sh"
echo "\n`env`" | grep 'LOG_DIR\|SERVICE_ROOT'
```

After running `sudo start test` content of /tmp/test.log will be:

```
running test.sh
SERVICE_ROOT=/data/service_root
LOG_DIR=/data/service_root/logs
```

In syslog you will find:

> Jul 16 01:39:39 vagrant-ubuntu-raring-64 /proc/self/fd/9: LOG_DIR='/data/service_root/logs'